# How to reset drop down if value change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm working on my project where I have three drop down boxes. User can pick Start time, Meeting Length and End time. My function works fine but I'm missing one more thing, so If user select all of three drop downs they will get all end times in last drop down but now I want if they change meeting length or start time, my end time drop box should give them values with the valid records. Current code works fine if they select everything once but if they change start time or meeting length my end time is still the same. 
Here is my jsfiddle with the working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/vy0yy7h9/4/

I tried to reset my function with something like this:

```
$('#meet_leng').on('chnage');
```

inside of my existing function but that did not help. If anyone knows how I can refresh my function each time after I change values in my start time and meeting length drop downs please let me know.

```js
$(function() {
  //This loop populate values fro meeting length dropdown
  for (var i = 5; i <= 60; i += 5) {
    $('#meet_leng').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + ' min' + '</option>')
  }

  //Populate start time dropdown with values 
  for (var i = 700; i <= 1700; i += 15) {
    var mins = i % 100;
    var hours = parseInt(i / 100);

    if (mins > 45) {
      mins = 0;
      hours += 1;
      i = hours * 100;
    }

    var AmPm = " AM";
    //set hours 12 to PM
    if (hours == 12) {
      AmPm = " PM";
    }

    //format all hours greater than to PM
    if (hours > 12) {
      hours = hours - 12;
      AmPm = " PM";
    }

    //populate stime with values
    $('#stime').append('<option value="' + ('0' + (hours)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + mins).slice(-2) + AmPm + '">' + ('0' + (hours)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + mins).slice(-2) + AmPm + ' </option>')
  }

  //onChange function set end time based on start time and meeting length
  $('#meet_leng').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#stime').val() == '0') {
      alert('You have to pick start time first.')
    } else {
      if ($('#meet_leng').val() == '0') {
        $('#hideSlots').hide();
      } else {
        //convert variables for start and end time to new Date
        var time1 = new Date();
        var time2 = new Date();

        //meeting length converts to int
        var meetingLength = parseInt($('#meet_leng').val());

        //start time split into hours and minutes
        var startTime = $('#stime').val();
        var startHour = startTime.split(':')[0];
        var startMin = startTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

        //end time split into hours and minutes
        var endTime = '05:00 PM';
        var endHour = endTime.split(':')[0];
        var endMin = endTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

        //Check if start time is PM and adjust hours to military
        if (startTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
          if (startHour != 12) {
            startHour = parseInt(startHour) + 12;
          } else {
            startHour = parseInt(startHour);
          }
        }

        //Check if end time is PM and adjust hours to military
        if (endTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
          endHour = parseInt(endHour) + 12;
        }

        //Date API start time set hours and minutes
        time1.setHours(parseInt(startHour));
        time1.setMinutes(parseInt(startMin));

        //Date API end time set hours and minutes
        time2.setHours(parseInt(endHour));
        time2.setMinutes(parseInt(endMin));

        //Adding meeting length to start time
        time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);

        //while loop checks for time values and increment end time for meeting interval  
        while (time1 <= time2) {
          var amPm = " AM";
          var hourEnd = time1.getHours();
          var minEnd = time1.getMinutes();

          if (hourEnd >= 12) {
            hourEnd = (hourEnd == 12) ? hourEnd : hourEnd - 12;
            amPm = " PM";
          }

          if (hourEnd == 24) {
            hourEnd = 12;
          }

          minEnd = ('' + minEnd).length > 1 ? minEnd : '0' + minEnd;

          $('#etime').append('<option value="' + hourEnd + ':' + minEnd + ' ' + amPm + '">' + hourEnd + ':' + minEnd + ' ' + amPm + '</option>');
          time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th>Start Time:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="stime" id="stime">
      <option value="0">--Select start time--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>
  <th>Metting Length:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="meet_leng" id="meet_leng">
      <option value="0">--Select length--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>
  <th>End Time:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="etime" id="etime" />
    <option value="0">--Select end time--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For one, don't use onload in jsfiddle if you have a `$(function() {})`

Comment: This is a bit confusing; do you just want to empty your `etime` select when a previous select is updated?

Comment: If i select 7:00 am start time, meeting length 15min my end time drop down give me all possible endtime values. But if I change meeting length after that my end time values do not change. That is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to either set the value:

```
$('#etime').val("new value");
```

or select the index:

```
$('#etime').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
```

remember that indexes start at 0.

you would do this after the while loop that populates all the end time options.

Comment: I tried second code that you provided and after I changed my meeting length my end time is still the same with all values that I got for my first time selected value in meeting length.

Comment: When you change meeting time the first time, you fill in options.  When you change it the second time, you do not take out the old options before putting in the new options, thus your options keep growing and growing.  The first index never changes, and thus your value stays the same.

The code answers the question.  Your application is not fully developed and requires more work than just the original question.

Comment: Code above does not answer the question, I asked if someone can help how to reset values in drop down. I know that my end time is accumulating values that is a reason why I want to clear drop down before I run onChnage function again. Thanks for help.

Comment: put this line before the while loop to remove previous options:

    $('#etime').children().not(":first").remove()

Comment: This works, I'm getting correct values and my end time drop down is clear. So I have one more question, why code has to be placed before while loop? I tried to do something similar but with .empty() command and that did not work for me.

Comment: .empty() should also work, but would remove your 0 value option as well.  I'd have to see what you wrote and where you put it to tell you why it didn't work.

It goes before the while loop because the while loop populates the new values.  If it was after the while loop then you'd lose all values.

Comment: I placed after while loop that's why my end drop down was always empty. Also .empty() I tried now instead of remove and drop down still was expanded but this time did not show old values and 0 was removed as you mentioned above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
     $('#meet_leng').on('chnage',function(){
            $('#etime').val("FirstIndexValue")
        });

//FirstIndexValue= #etime default value
```

Comment: This code just changed my end time and set the value to 0 but did not give me a new values in end time drop down.